# php mysql calculate each percentage

Tags: php, mysql

how do i calculate percentage in mysql for each user?

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM report LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id= report.id_user WHERE date='$today' GROUP BY id_user");
$q1 = $db->query("SELECT SUM(r_amount) AS total FROM report WHERE date='$today' AND id_user=id_user");
$r1 = $q1->fetch_assoc();
$totalCharge = $r1['totalCharge'];
$sixtyPercent = $totalCharge * 0.60;
$fortyPercent = $totalCharge * 0.40;

while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$r['user_name].'</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">'.$fortyPercent.'</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">'.$sixtyPercent.'</td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><strong></strong></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
endwhile;


current result:

name     60% cut    40% cut    total 
user 1   60         40         100
user 2   60         40         100
user 3   60         40         100

expecting result:

name     60% cut    40% cut    total 
user 1   60         40         100
user 2   24         16         40
user 3   48         32         80
```

Comment: The reason the values are repeated down the column is that you are setting $totalCharge = $r1['totalCharge'] and calculating the $sixtyPercent & $fortyPercent off of that.  From then on, the two variables are constant, which gives your current result's behavior.

Comment: Why have you kept calculation out of the while????

Comment: @Phaxian: Go ahead and post that as an actual reply, I'm pretty sure that's the correct answer.  Those variables should be set *inside* the while loop so that they change per user.

Comment: thats why i posted my code in here :) i just ran out of idea to calculate inside while loop. You all might have a better solution. please do share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't getting the expected results because your `$totalCharge` variable will never change (nor will it ever match the proper user_id).

Most likely what you'll want to do is write a SQL statement which combines the two statements you currently have, then simply loop through the results of that statement and do all of the calculations within that loop.

The SQL statement might look something like:

```
SELECT SUM(r_amount) AS totalCharge, report.*, user.* 
FROM report 
JOIN total ON total.id_user = report.id_user 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id= report.id_user 
WHERE date='$today' GROUP BY user_id
```

You'll likely have to tweak it a little to get the expected results.

Then your loop will look something like:

```
while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $totalCharge = $r['totalCharge'];
    $sixtyPercent = $totalCharge * 0.60;
    $fortyPercent = $totalCharge * 0.40;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$r['user_name'].'</td>';        // corrected syntax error here
    echo '<td align="center">'.$sixtyPercent.'</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">'.$fortyPercent.'</td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><strong></strong></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Hope this guides you to the solution.